# Android java apk with white screen after return from camera intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

In my java apk I use this code to launch the camera:

```
   cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
   cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.quickCapture", true);
   //File photoFile = createImageFile();
   //Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "com.lo.test.provider", photoFile);
   //cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
   startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

In the onActivityResult method, for many different devices, I can get the return flow and work with the photos I take. But with a few devices I get a white screen with message log like this:

```
2023-10-22 01:45:02.056 13137-13137 System.out              com.lo.test                 I  Fin de openCameraIntent 
2023-10-22 01:45:02.056 13137-13137 Second Activity         com.lo.test                 V  Fin de openCameraIntent 
2023-10-22 01:45:12.449 13137-13150 o.test         com.lo.test                 W  Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 111 to 100
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (13137) for package com.lo.test ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (17417) for package com.lo.test ----------------------------
2023-10-22 01:45:21.991 17417-17417 ActivityThread          com.lo.test                 I  Relaunch all activities: onCoreSettingsChange
2023-10-22 01:45:22.040 17417-17417 ziparchive              com.lo.test                 W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~w5RdZZDsNzvS9Unhg0IXiw==/com.lo.test-hPTUSB_ZDsOQzoOcVmvj9w==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2023-10-22 01:45:22.040 17417-17417 ziparchive              com.lo.test                 W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~w5RdZZDsNzvS9Unhg0IXiw==/com.lo.test-hPTUSB_ZDsOQzoOcVmvj9w==/base.dm': No such file or directory
```

At this point the queries to database all of them return like no data in database(the database has data)

And after that the apk crash.

EDIT:
The log file https://easyupload.io/2wpxve

Any idea?

Comment: "In the onActivityResult method" -- FWIW, [that `Intent` action does not return a result](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/MediaStore?hl=en#intent_action_still_image_camera). "with message log like this" -- there is little to go on there. However, please bear in mind that your process might be terminated while your UI is in the background and the camera app is in the foreground. The "Relaunch all activities" line suggests that perhaps this is what happened to you.

Comment: "the queries to database all of them return like no data in database" -- that code is not in your question, so it will be difficult for us to help with it. "And after that the apk crash" -- look for a stack trace associated with the crash.

Comment: On the activityresult I don´t use a result from the camera, I just get the list of photos using a Cursor in another thread: 

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, selection, selectionArgs, orderBy);




About the database code it work if no white screen present, for example:
String sql = "select * from plazas Where email= '" + GlobalMembers.GM_EMAIL + "'";
SQLiteDatabase db = SqliteDB.getInstance(this).getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

Comment: "I just get the list of photos using a Cursor in another thread" -- note that there is no requirement for the camera app you are starting to save an image on the device in a publicly available location, and there is no requirement for it to be indexed by `MediaStore` by the time control returns to your app.

Comment: that´s right, this is why I put a delay about 2s and after that I return to the main activity flow and can pull the images from CDIM folder using the list of paths from the query to MediaStore. It work in many differents phones but I need it work in all. Event if I not take a single picture, just open the camera and close it, I get on those phones a white screen. No in my phone, not in another phones. I will put a log file in my question.

Comment: "It work in many differents phones" -- it also depends on the camera app. "It work in many differents phones but I need it work in all" -- then use CameraX or another camera library and take the photo yourself.

Comment: Can you take a look to the log file?